# Confusion over choosing Faye or Rails 4 Actioncontroller::Live

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, websocket, real-time, faye

I have already used Faye with Ruby On Rails, it's almost at 0 cost for me, because I'm running Faye over another server connected to my Rails App.

However I have faced some problems like when a query takes too long on the Rails server, after a while the Faye Connection would fail and raise an exception.

Now what I'm looking into the Actioncontroller::Live , most of the implementations are using Redis, which will be a bit costy for my startup, however I realized I can't do subscribe/publish style things with the Actioncontroller::Live.

**My question:** should I move over to Actioncontroller::Live or stick to Faye ? While these are the things that I want to accomplish:

1. Updates after commenting/feed
2. Notification system, based on pub/sub, similar to Faye.
3. Exception handling
4. Scalability > More users more connections

I know that Faye uses Bayeux vs ActionController::live uses SSE/ HTTP.
Should I consider anything related to Socket.IO ? SockJS ?

I have already read through some of the question about this topic on here like:
[Replace Faye with rails 4 server side events? Faye VS rails 4 streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902370/replace-faye-with-rails-4-server-side-events-faye-vs-rails-4-streaming)
But I need more info:

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's some notes on why I would stick with Faye, which might bring you closer to an answer on this question:

**Browser compatibility**

As you read in the related stackoverflow question, Faye has better browser compatibility.

**Stability**

Rails::Live functionality doesn't seem to be very stable yet.  There's currently active development on Rails SSE.  As an example, it's quite unlikely that you won't be affected by [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10989).

**Threading & blocking vs asynchronous non-blocking**

Do you use multi-threading in your application?  If you don't, I definitely wouldn't introduce it just for Rails::Live as it opens up the possibility of non-threadsafe gem issues & limitations of server choices.

If you do have multi-threading, each client will keep a thread open to your application.  If you run out of threads your application will be unresponsive/dead.  Consider how many threads you need to cater for peak times with users having multiple browser tabs open, or even DOS attacks where someone opens up a huge amount of idle SSE/websocket connections to reach your max and take your app down.  If you set a high amount of max threads to support many idle connections, you open up the possibility of having that many non-idle threads which could have it's own problems.  No SSE/websockets and no comet/long polling is much safer for blocking apps.  From what I understand, your setup runs Faye separately.  The Faye server runs Ruby EventMachine or Node.js which are both asynchronous non-blocking and do not use a thread for each open connection.  It can handle a huge amount of concurrent connections without problems.

My opinion is that a normal blocking Rails web application with a separate asynchronous non-blocking server for connections that stay open (to pass messages & make the app live) is the best of both setup.  This is what you have with Rails + Faye.

**Update**: [Actioncable](https://github.com/rails/actioncable) was announced at Railsconf 2015.  It runs non-blocking as described above, but it's an integrated official Rails solution.  Having a single framework with a massive community, an integrated non-blocking connection handler for websockets that you can run and configure separately while everything works "out of the box" is a big advantage of Rails.

**From Action Cable readme**:
*Action Cable is powered by a combination of EventMachine and threads. The framework plumbing needed for connection handling is handled in the EventMachine loop, but the actual channel, user-specified, work is handled in a normal Ruby thread. This means you can use all your regular Rails models with no problem, as long as you haven't committed any thread-safety sins.*

To learn more you can read up on [ActionCable & Underlying architecture](https://medium.com/techracers/actioncable-underlying-architecture-part-1-2-f110b7d5634e).

Comment: Thank you so much for the sound of confidence in answering. I decided to go that way as well. I realized the seucrity risk and downtime problems if I go the other way by choosing something over Faye + Rails. Thanks again :), sometime soon I'm planning to swrite a blog about this, and dfntly use your answer as point of proof as well :)!

Comment: Did you write that blog?
Any chance for a link?

Comment: I agree with the last paragraph. Despite all the Node.js hype, Rails is still the superior choice.